# Why does _XBEGIN_STARTED equal -1?

Tags: c, transactions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int x = 0;

    while(true) {
        if(_xbegin() != _XBEGIN_STARTED) {
            printf("Transaction failed, retrying\n");
            continue;
        }

        x++;
        printf("Transaction done\n");

        _xend();
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So here I haven't declared _XBEGIN_STARTED, and when I tried to print its value, it appears to be -1 instead of 0.

Comment: Before the XBEGIN-instruction the compiler loads EAX with -1. After XBEGIN, it compares EAX with -1. If it is still -1 it's the beginning of the transaction. If it is not, the transaction has been rolled back and there's a code for the transaction-abort in EAX different from -1 so that the code can chose what to do at a rollback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's never been declared/defined as something, it's wrong to think it will be zero. What *will* happen in that case is that your compiler will complain bitterly that it knows nothing *about* `_XBEGIN_STARTED`.

The fact that it's *not* complaining means that something *has* defined it and, if you're getting `-1` when you print it out, it's a safe bet to say it's being defined as that value.

---

The definition of `_XBEGIN_STARTED` is in [`rtmintrin.h`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/rtmintrin_8h.html) which is, in turn, included by your [`immintrin.h`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/immintrin_8h_source.html) file. All this stuff has to do with transactional memory.

In the `rtm` header file, you can see `_XBEGIN_STARTED` clearly defined as the bit inversion of `0` which will, if you print it out as a signed number (in a two's complement environment), give you `-1`:

```
#define XBEGIN_STARTED  (~0u)
```